# When will Apache IoTDB clean up historical data after TTL is set to certain value?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

May I ask how long it will take for the expired historical data to be automatically cleared after the TTL is set to a time value in Apache IoTDB V0.13.3? Also, if I currently set TTL=1, are the historical data before that 1 day will be cleaned up after I restart IoTDB, or IoTDB judges and starts at a certain time period to clean them up?

I checked the official guide and all perfomred instructions in IoTDB website, but still do not understand this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current time - the time (ms) set by TTL of Apache IoTDB will be the retained data time range. Data outside this range will be automatically deleted.
If you set TTL to 1 day in iotdb-cli, the historical data of 1 day from the current time will be started to clean up after you hit the Enter key.